# Could 0x800CCC0E in Outlook be caused by bad wireless connection?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, 64-bit, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a computer connected to a WiFi access point/router/modem. Sometimes, I get page not found errors and similar when opening a browser window, sometimes pings fail and it looks like the router's signal isn't very good. On the other hand, I get around 4 bars of signal strength in windows and graph looks good in Inssider. I also never get dropped connection to the router.

My main problem is that I often get errors (such as 0x800CCC0E) in Outlook 2010 that after some searching appear to be connected to bad server connection. I'm using GMail over IMAP and all settings are correct. I didn't have similar errors on my previous router, but I'm not 100% sure that they appeared after switching to current one. It may have worked for some time without errors. There are also around 3000 messages on the server and the size of mailbox is around 12 GiB, which may contribute to the problems.

On the other hand, there are at least 24 other networks in the 2.4 GHz range which I'm using and the number may have increased since I switched routers.

Should I try solving this by getting a router with stronger signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me at least, the answer was yes. I got a router with stronger signal and problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a backup copy of your mailbox and then try to repair it because part of it might be corrupted.

Comment: How do I do that?